# How to get part of a URL and convert to string in django python?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple blog website in django and I want to include video embeds using this script:

```
<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<div id="youtubeplayer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    video: "627627612"
  };
  var player = new Twitch.Player("youtubeplayer", options);
  player.setVolume(0.5);
</script>
```

I have a URL field on the Post model. I want to then take that URL and only take part of it to fill in the "video" parameter in the above script. So, for example we have Twitch video URL `https://www.twitch.tv/videos/494181151` and I want to take the `494181151` and convert to string so I can fill it in to the "video" parameter above in an html template.

Is this possible and how can I go about doing it? I know I have to check for the URL and then check if it contains part of the URL like this:

```
{% if url %}
{% if 'twitch.tv/videos' in url %}
```

But I'm not sure how to get the last part of the URL.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Nalin I was able to create a method in the Post model to extract the video ID correctly. However, when I use the variable in the html template, all I see is some Javascript printing onto the web page. `var options = { width: 800, height: 500, ...`

Here is my updated html template:

```
 {% if post.video_URL %}
    <script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
    <div id='youtubeplayer'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var options = {
           width: 800,
           height: 500,
           video: "{{ post.get_video_id }}"
       };
       var player = new Twitch.Player("youtubeplayer", options);
       player.setVolume(0.5);
      </script> 
{% endif %}
```

Here's the model method if needed but it seems to be working correctly if I simply print `{{ post.get_video_id }}`. There's only an issue when I try to include it in the above javascript to embed the Twitch video.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    content_text = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=3000)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',
                         unique_with=['user__username', 'created_date'])
    tags = TaggableManager()
    video_URL = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name='Video/VOD/Clip URL')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_video_id(self):
        video_id = self.video_URL.split('/')[-1]  # will return str
        return video_id
```

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split the url to get the video id.

```
video_url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/videos/494181151'
video_id = video_url.split('/')[-1]  # will return str
```

Then you can return `video_id` in your context. Then in your template, you can do something like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
{% if video_id %}
  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    video: "{{ video_id }}"
  };
  var player = new Twitch.Player("youtubeplayer", options);
  player.setVolume(0.5);
{% endif %}
</script>
```

You might have to add extra checks while splitting the string.

Comment: thank you! How can I do this if I'm looping through multiple Post objects? My view is using ` posts = Post.objects.all`, then I loop through them in the html template. Can I set video_id in the html template?

Comment: @winston create a instance `def get_video_id(self)` method in your models.py and return video_id from that method and call that method in template as `{{ post.get_video_id }}`.

Comment: thank you very much, that method correctly extracts the video ID from the URL. However, it looks like the javascript code is printing onto the website via the html template. I updated my question. I feel I am finally very close to solving this thanks to you!

Comment: it is kind of unexpected, can you add some photo of that behavior? also add you model method in your post.

Comment: I solved the issue! It was due to a conflicting javascript plugin. Thank you for helping me solve the original problem!